# QGIS print composer: Transparency in legend symbols

Tags: qgis, legend

Is there a way to make the legend in the QGIS (v2.0.1) print composer reflect the same degree of transparency as set in the Style box in the main window? The legend symbol colours are shown with no transparency but these look very different to the transparent colours on the map...

Doing a search of this question on a different website I found the following answer:
"There are two transparency sliders in the style dialog. Altering the big 
one at the top doesn't affect the transparency of the legend symbol or 
the style preview in the dialog, but the small transparency slider below 
the size unit selector does."

However, I only see one transparency slider in the style dialog. Or am I looking in the wrong place? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Layer Transparency versus Symbol Transparency]You can set transprency at two levels, the "Layer Transparency" and/or the "Symbol Layers".

Selecting Style in the Layer Properties you should see Layer Transparency under the Style heading on the right. This affects the layer but does not affect the symbol in the legend. (Long transparency slider and box)

Selecting Style and going to the Symbol Fill properties you should have access to another level of transparency. This will affect layer fill transparency for the selected symbol and will show up in the legend. (Transparency Slider only, assuing Single Symbol mode)

Comment: How to achieve this goal with QGIS 3.22+? The legend symbol behaves the same when you set global layer transparency, as well as capacity in the symbol of single-band pseudocolor representation.